# Webstorm не подсвечивает несоответствие типов props React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webstorm

Пусть у меня есть интерфейс, который должен описывать props для `SomeComponent`.

```
type ISomeComponentProps = {
    size: number,
    transactionType: 'type1' | 'type2',
    isActive: boolean
}
```

А также сам `SomeComponent`

```
const SomeComponent = ({size, transactionType, isActive, isPending}: ISomeComponentProps) => {
    const propsLikeObj: ISomeComponentProps = {
        size: 10,
        transactionType: 'type1',
        isActive: true,
        isPending: true
    }

    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

И во время деструктурирования props, и во время создания `propsLikeObj` я использую один интерфейс, однако WebStorm в во втором случае ругается, а в первом - нет. Как сделать так, чтобы он ругался на несоответствие props своему интерфейсу? То же самое касается ситуации, когда мы `SomeComponent` используем в других компонентах, и не передаем ему нужное количество props.